# How can we view uploaded files in data browser in parse.com?

Tags: image, upload, parse-platform, image-uploading, image-upload

I am using parse.com as a data storage backend for one of my web app.

I want to upload images on parse.com and I was successful in uploading images to parse.com and parse is returning a long unique URL for uploaded image as well.

When I tried to open the image using returned URL, image was opened which means upload was successful.

However I am not able to see uploaded images in parse.com file browser. Can someone suggest how to view all uploaded images in file browser?

Thanks

Comment: By "file browser" I assume you mean the "Hosting" tab, where cloud code files are deployed. You won't see uploaded images there. You can't browse those files anywhere. You have to access them through data browser, or query them in code.

Comment: Yes, I thought there should be some way to browse them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to view these files is to download them and then view them locally. To do this you must do the following.

1. In the Parse data browser, navigate to the file cell.
2. Click on the cell, and choose a download location.
3. Open the file on your local machine.

Note: The file you download won't have an extension so you might have to specify the application you want to open the file. In your case it would be an image viewer.